# Best way to access form input values

Tags: jquery

I have the following two variables.  I will send the data variable to the server, and upon return, want to access the various original values.

I could do some sort of eq(1).val() approach to either the data or raw variable, but then need to make sure I am accessing them in the right order which might result in future maintenance issues.  Or I can get the values from the original DOM using the name selector, but it seems like I am doing the work twice.  Or I can add IDs as well as names to the original form, but that seems like a waste.

Ideally, I would be able to convert the form's name/value to some sort of object, but unlike serializeArray would not make an array, but have the value directed tied to the name.  For instance, if my form had `<input name="foo" value="bar">`, I would be able to access the value as newObject.foo.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

```
var raw=$("#form_id").find('input,select');
var data=raw.serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by directly accessing the form:

```
var form = $("#form_id")[0];
console.log( form.foo.value );
```

Comment: Esailija,  Liked you first response before you edited it.  My problem with this approach is every time you change the layout of the page, the order changes and consequentially the values.

Comment: @user1032531 Do you mean the names? As long as a form has `<input name="foo">` then `form.foo` will refer to that input and `form.foo.value` will  refer to the input's value. The order, or the values, don't matter. If you really mean that the **names** change, then you cannot do `newObject.foo` either because `foo` has changed its name.

Answer (score 1):

```
var formVals = [];
$('select, input').each(function(i, v){
   formVals[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: I am actually leaning towards..
var fields = {};
raw.each(function() {fields[this.name] = $(this).val();});

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery allows you to select every inputs (even selects, radio and checkbox, which ar not actually inputs at once) to build that array with serializeArray():

```
var object = $(":input").serializeArray();
```

From the jQuery docs here : http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/
Of course, restrict that $(":inputs") to the tragetted form especially if you gave multiple forms in your document.

This should get you an object looking like:

[
  {
    name: "foo",
    value: "bar"
  },
  {
     ...
  }
]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I would serialize the inputs and form fields:

```
var result = $('form').serializeArray();
```

Then get individual objects:

```
result.ObjectName;
```

Comment: I want the original data, not the returned data.  var objects = $.parseJSON(result); gives me null.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the original data?

Comment: Original data is the original form data, and not the reply from the server.

Comment: what is the point of calling `$.parseJSON` with an array as argument

Answer (score 0):

```
var raw=$("#form_id").find('input,select');
```

This is more efficient.
This has been proved in the [Jsperf Performance test here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-1-4-2-vs-1-6-2-comparisons)
It shows the above method outperforms other test cases in almost all browsers.
Though direct get method of `var item = $(".buttonRef");` outperforms in some cases.
Note:Ids are accessible faster than classes though it is not recommended in most of the cases.
When it comes to efficiency of time when accessing form input values u might consider ids.

[Note Reference](http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks)

I dunno if I got your question right.

Comment: I don't know if you got my question right either, but liked your response.  Thanks